# iOS 14: Allow Location Access | Always menu not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14

I tried to run my project in Xcode 12 beta 2 with iOS 14 simulator. I observed "Always" menu is not found in Allow Location Access Setting screen.

[image]

I have given the followings info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>TEST APP</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>TEST APP</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>TEST APP</string>
```

Comment: Is 'always' menu not only coming in simulators?

Comment: update the post with code you are using to request for location permission.

Comment: @Bilal,  I have used whenInUse request. But this is independent right. I am going to app setting and I tried to change the location permission

Comment: I observed this issue too. If I run app on device with iOS 14 beta 2, always is there

Comment: I am observing the same behavior as of Xcode 12 Beta 3 and iOS 14.0. Regardless what what permissions I ask for on simulator it never shows "Always" option, on the other hand on device it always shows "Always" option regardless of what permissions I ask for. This is clearly a behaviour that is different on device and simulator.

Comment: I created this feedback and let's see if they reply something https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/8223899

Answer (score 7):

The "Always Allow" option has been removed from **the initial location permissions prompt**. You can get this option later as a new prompt. Then the question comes, how will we support the location feature if we need it in the background?

[image]

Way to achieve this -

1. Call the method **"locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()"** before your app can receive location information. If your app needs always permission and you want to receive the prompt for always permission later.
2. Initially, users can select "While Using the app" or select a new option, "Allow Once"(introduced in iOS 13 itself).
3. If the user continues to use the app, iOS 13 will now automatically prompt to upgrade location permissions from "While Using the app" to "Always Allow".

   [image]
4. You will receive #2 prompt next time after unlocking the device and launching the app with already grated "While Using the app" permission.

**Source**

This WWDC 2019 video also suggests that this is still possible: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/705/

At 6:57 "...you can request when in use authorization first, then, at some later point, when the user interacts with a feature of the app that warrants it, seek always authorization later..."

Answer (score 3):

I have also observed this issue and filed feedback about it — no response so far apart from there being "less than 10" other reports about it.

There seems to be a workaround using the `simctl` command line tool:

```
xcrun simctl privacy booted grant location-always <bundle identifier>
```

This enables the "Always" option in Settings.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a few updates in location management for iOS 14.

One of them is that `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)` is now deprecated, so you need to implement `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_:)` in your CLLocationManager instead.

You also need to make sure you are calling the `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` function on your Location Manager.  From [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization) about this function:

> You must call this or the requestWhenInUseAuthorization() method before your app can receive location information.

Comment: I have some queries while doing some changes for ios 14. If we implement new method then we have to remove deprecated one ? And if we do this changes that never affect on other iOS version below ios 14. Please help me to understand this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. From what I can tell, this is/was a bug with the first several Beta versions of Xcode 12. I upgraded to Beta #6 when it came out this morning, and the issue has now gone away for me. See if that fixes it for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever you request in your app same options appear in settings of your app.

If you have requested for when in use authorization only using `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` method of `CLLocationManager` only `While Using the App` will appear in your app settings.

If you request for always using `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` `Always` option will appear in your app settings.

You can request for both `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` and `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` at some point in your app depending on your use case.

Comment: I was not calling requestAlwaysAuthorization(), but I can see 'always' menu in the location permission setting screen in iOS 13 simulator

Comment: As far as I know behaviour is same for IOS 13. You can try the IOS 13 simulator again (Reset the simulator first to make sure all the existing app settings are gone)

Comment: @Sridhar if you are seeing Always option in IOS13. You or any other third party SDK must have requested for Always permission. You can do a quick test, just create a new sample app and just request for While In Use permission, run the app and verify the permissions in app settings.

Comment: What you described is not true. On simulator it never shows "Always" regardless of what permissions you ask for. On device, it always shows "Always" regardless of what you ask for. This is clearly a buggy behaviour.